# 18.04 does not recognize monitors or drivers after graphic card change

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia

Before I was working with build in graphic card, all worked fine. Now I set nvidia quadro p620 with DP connection.

The problem: Only one monitor recognized and it's resolution is 800x600, nothing more than this in settings. 
Nvidia X server settings not load at all.

I've reinstalled drivers x times through console, through "sofware & updates", in terminal mode, I've downloaded the driver from nvidia website and ./run it. Nothing helps.

So what I have in

```
xrandr

xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 800 x 600, current 800 x 600, maximum 800 x 600
default connected primary 800x600+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   800x600       75.00* 




lspci -k | grep -iEA5 'vga|display|3d'


01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL [Quadro P620] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1264
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

Comment: Did you enable the Nvidia adapter by running `sudo prime-select nvidia`, then logging out and logging back in?

Comment: @user3140225 yes.. "Info: the nvidia profile is already set"

Answer (score 1):

It was BIOS misconfiguration. So the video adapter was set to AUTO and somehow even "sudo prime-select nvidia", I specified the video adapter and all worked.